# How to remove last character of repeated x and after that strings ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Data is [one][two][three]
I dont want the last set including brackets I need result like [one][two]
How to do with the help of jquery.

Comment: Can you please mention with code e.g input and expected output. put the code which you've tried

Comment: Could you be more specific? It's not exactly clear what logic you're trying to implement.

Comment: what does this mean? I can even understand that you do not post an attempt, but at least try to post a meaningful question

Comment: can you be clearer of what is exactly your data? Is that a string? an array or object where you want to remove a part?

Comment: @Venkatesh Srikanth: firstly the question is not understandable and provides your code what you have done so that you can achieve your solution.

Comment: var names = ([one][two][three]);
var exc = names.match(/.*\[([^)]+)\]/)[1];
but the result is three]

Comment: Need result like [one][two]

Comment: Are one two and three always dynamic or they're always the same?

Comment: it is dynamic I dont want the last set [ xxx ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use replace instead of match:

```js
console.log("[one][two][three]".replace(/\[[^[]*\]$/, ''))
```

Explaining the regular expression:

- `\[` matches a literal `[` character
- `[^[]*` matches a series of characters that do **not** contain `[`
- `\]` matches the literal `]` character
- `$` anchors the expression to the end to the string

Comment: Could you kindly explain the `[^[]*`? I get that it matches the first `[` and the last `]` that are at the end, how does `[^[]*` tell it that the first `[` is the third one? (sorry, I'm not that good at regex and wishing to learn), so can you edit your answer and explain a bit further please?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy: It is the last one, because the regex is anchored to end of the string (with `$`) and since there can be no `[` characters in the match (`[^[]*`), is has to be the last match

Comment: Could you still kindly detail `[^[]*`? Which part is the not?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy: The `^` is negation inside the `[ ... ]`. For example `[^a]` is any character except `a`.